# How to make rails devise function after merging on another system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, devise

I set up devise on a local machine for my user authentication and it works fine there. But when I log into the server and merge the local changes there it throws the error:

```
devise_for in routes.rb not found
```

After executing the install command `rails g device:install` on the server it now states:

```
undefined method 'user_signed_in?'
```

Does anybody know how I make `devise` work after the cloning or merging?

Comment: I did that already. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: You mean `rails g devise:install`? You should not run that on your production server. You should run it locally, optionally write a few tests to make sure it is working and commit the resulting files.

Comment: I did it locally and it runs there. But when I commited and pushed it and then pulled on the server it rendered the first error mentioned:
`devise_for in routes.rb not found`

I thought when I rerun this command then maybe it sets up some config information and would run again, but that lead to the second error `undefined method 'user_sigend_int?'`.

I don't know how to proceed. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

I used capistrano for deployment which set up the right production settings.
There I had to disable `config.i18n.fallbacks = false`.
Actually I do not know why it works now, but I think it could have to do with cached locale information.